# XSLT Transformation issue - how to populate attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes

I am using xslt first time. I have to create an element based on some criteria.

here is i/p xml:

```
<FirstUser>
   <User id="2" description="ABC" Type="HR"/>
</FirstUser>
<SecondUser>
  <User id="3" description="ABC" Type="HR"/>
  <User id="4" description="xyz" Type="Admin"/>
  <User id="5" description="LMN" Type="Payroll"/>
</SecondUser>
```

**Final O/P**

```
<AllUsers isFromHR='true'>
  <User id="2" description="ABC" Type="HR"/>
  <User id="3" description="ABC" Type="HR"/>
  <User id="4" description="xyz" Type="Admin"/>
  <User id="5" description="LMN" Type="Payroll"/>
</AllUsers>
```

Business Rule: AllUsers element has 1 attribute isFromHR - 
Its value w'd be true if value in type attribute of `<FirstUser>` or `<SecondUser>`
is HR else it will be false

How to populate the value of isFromHR ? Rest of xml creation I am done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XML examples are not well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
<AllUsers isFromHR="{ count((//FirstUser | //SecondUser)[@type='HR']) &gt; 0 }">
```

or

```
<AllUsers>
    <xsl:attribute 
         name="isFromHR"
         value="count((//FirstUser | //SecondUser)[@type='HR']) &gt; 0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <AllUsers>
      <xsl:attribute name="isFromHR">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//*[local-name(.)='FirstUser' or local-name(.)='SecondUser']/*/@Type[.='HR']">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </AllUsers >
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Many many thanks SIR... This trick worked. 
I w'd be extremely happy If I could get some soft copy material to read as I am new to xslt World.

I have few more queries regarding various xslt functions and use of variables... so If you could provide me some softcopy to study...will be good for me.

Once again many Thanks :-)

Comment: Check out the XSLT http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp and XPATH http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp tutorials on http://w3schools.com, to get started.  Dave Pawson maintains a very useful site: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/  The FAQ's distill many common problems, explainations, and code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
<AllUsers isFromHR="{descendant::@type = 'HR'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The input XML is missing elements:

```
<FirstUser>
   <User id="2" description="ABC" Type="HqR"/>
</FirstUser>
<SecondUser>
  <User id="3" description="ABC" Type="H2R"/>
  <User id="4" description="xyz" Type="Admin"/>
  <User id="5" description="LMN" Type="Payroll"/>
</SecondUser>
```

In any case, I'd go for:

```
<AllUsers isFromHR="{//FirstUser/User/@Type = 'HR' or //SecondUser/User/@Type = 'HR'}">
```

This gives you "true" in case either FirstUser or SecondUser contains a User of type 'HR'.